# Schedule automatic daily upload with FileZilla

Tags: automation, upload, sftp, ftp-client, filezilla

I would like to use FileZilla to automatically upload PDFs to my GoDaddy hosted site daily, replacing the previous day's sheets. Is there any way to do this? I read online that batch files might work, could someone post a sample version of a batch file that would do the trick?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

FileZilla does not have any command line arguments (nor any other way) that allow an automatic transfer.

Some references:

- [FileZilla Client command-line arguments](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Command-line_arguments_(Client))
- https://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/2317
- [How do I send a file with FileZilla from the command line?](https://superuser.com/q/239860/213663)

---

Though you can use any other client that allows automation.

You have not specified, what protocol you are using. FTP or SFTP? You will definitely be able to use WinSCP, as it supports all protocols that the free version of FileZilla does (and more).

Combine [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting) capabilities with Windows Scheduler:

- [Automate file transfers to FTP server or SFTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation);
- [Schedule file transfers to FTP/SFTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_schedule)

A typical WinSCP script for upload (with SFTP) looks like:

```
open sftp://user:password@example.com/ -hostkey="ssh-rsa 2048 xxxxxxxxxxx...="
put c:\mypdfs\*.pdf /home/user/
close
```

With FTP, just replace the `sftp://` with the `ftp://` and remove the `-hostkey="..."` switch.

---

Similarly for download: [How to schedule an automatic FTP download on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21293019/850848)

---

WinSCP can even [generate a script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating) from an [imported FileZilla session](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_import).

For details, see the [guide to FileZilla automation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_filezilla_automation).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

---

Another option, if you are using SFTP, is the [`psftp.exe` client from PuTTY suite](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter6.html#psftp).

Comment: very good one, works like a charm!

Comment: The OP's question may not meet SO guidelines, but the answer sure is useful information! Moderators, since this page is up top when you google 'filezilla schedule upload', please consider re-enabling answers to allow for improved answers to land here also.