# Schedule weekly Excel file download to an unique name

Tags: excel, ftp, scheduled-tasks

We got a database where every Monday a Excel file gets uploaded from a client. The file is always the same name so if we forgot it we lost it. Is there a way how we can make a script that renames the script and gives it the date or a number?

We're using FileZilla to get the files now.

Comment: Do you want to make a script that automatically runs every Monday, connects to an FTP (or an SFTP) server, downloads a file with a fixed name to a local folder, saving it to a name that is different each time?

Comment: yes would be nice, its a FTP server and i want it to download the file to a local folder with a different name every time. but thats exactly what i mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileZilla [does not allow any kind of automation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24945709/850848).

---

You can use this [WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation):

```
open ftp://user:password@host/
get "/path/sheet.xls" "c:\archive\sheet-%TIMESTAMP#yyyy-mm-dd%.xls"
exit
```

The script connects to the server, downloads the sheet to a local archive under a name like `sheet-YYYY-MM-DD.xls`.

For details see:

- [Automate file transfers (or synchronization) to FTP server or SFTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation)
- [Downloading file to timestamped-filename](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_download_timestamped_filename)

---

Then create a task in Windows scheduler to run the `winscp.exe` every Monday with arguments:

```
/script="c:\path_to_script\script.txt" /log="c:\path_to_script\script.log"
```

[Logging (`/log=...`)](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#logging) is optional, but it's recommended.

For details, see [Schedule file transfers (or synchronization) to FTP/SFTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_schedule).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer i'm gonna use it, going to setup it now.

Comment: i made the script and edited the path and user password and host but it after that i followed the instructions from your site for windows scheduler but it seems that it cant be found i probably did something wrong but i cant see the task and its also not running.

Comment: *it cant be found*: What is it that cannot be found?

Comment: the task in scheduler it says The selected task [0] does not exist, refresh if you want to show the current tasks. translated it but it is something like that.

Comment: Can you make a screenshot, upload it somewhere and post a link?

Comment: http://i58.tinypic.com/b7ct2u.png and this is the error but its dutch, the code in script.txt is: open ftp://hrnet:password@ftp.hrnetwerk.nl/
get "/test.xls" "c:\test-%TIMESTAMP#yyyy-mm-dd%.xls"
exit   i changed the password above here but is is the good one in the real file

Comment: It looks good to me. Works for me with the same settings. Does the task disappear when you refresh the view?