# How do I automate a file transfer from some server to My computer's folder through winscp?

Tags: linux, shell, winscp

I have to move few (.csv) files from server to one folder of my computer. I use winscp for this task.

I have to do this everyday at certain time, say 10 AM. Sometimes I wouldn't be availble at that time. So how should I automate this task?

I have searched about scheduling a task from task manager in windows 7 and use winSCP script.

I know only shell, and C programming. I am not familiar with these WinSCP scripts. Please help if anybody can.

Comment: Highly recommend you to use a unix or linux based machines to administration tasks. I'm not sure if you can schedule such tasks in windows. I you have a linux or unix machine. You can use cronjob to run your scp command.

Comment: Thank you. I am running cronjob in linux machine, but I require this thing to be done on windows machine as I would be needing MS excel's help and then email this file via Outlook.

Comment: Here you go . This link explains how to schedule a task http://www.pcworld.com/article/2603028/automate-your-morning-programs-with-windows-task-scheduler.html
This link explains the winscp arguments https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Schedule automatic daily upload with FileZilla](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24945709/schedule-automatic-daily-upload-with-filezilla) (while the question is about FileZilla, [my] answer shows how to do it with WinSCP, because FileZilla cannot be automated).

Comment: Thank you all for your good help.

I-V can you tell me how do I transfer a file from a server linux machine (in MTPUTTY) to some folder in desktop (windows 7) by SCP command?

Comment: @I-V What scp has to do with samba? Those are two different technologies to do a similar task, they are not to be used together. And neither is easy to set up.