# Auto delete all files in an FTP folder every 30 minutes

Tags: php, ftp, filezilla

Is there a way to delete all files from an FTP folder every 30 minutes automatically?

Let's say that my details are the following:

- Folder: /myfolder
- Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
- Username: myname
- Password: mypassword

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where do you want to run the delete process from? What platform? Why do you tag "php"? Why do you tag "filezilla"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a file abc.php and write this code

`array_map('unlink', glob("/myfolder/*"));`

after that schedule a corn for hit this file every 30 min

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you provide any details about scheduling a corn? I have not experience on that.

Comment: if using VPS then read this link `https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-cron-to-automate-tasks-on-a-vps`

Answer (score 2):

It's not really clear what do you ask for.

But if you want to automate the deletion via FileZilla, you cannot. [FileZilla does not support any automation/scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24945709/850848).

You have to use another FTP client. On Windows, you can use [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/).

A simple batch file (`.bat`) to delete files from FTP folder using [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting) is like:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
  /log="C:\writable\path\to\log\WinSCP.log" /ini=nul ^
  /command ^
    "open ftp://myname:mypassword@ftp.example.com/" ^
    "rm /myfolder/*" ^
    "exit"
```

---

To schedule the batch file run, use the Windows scheduler. See [WinSCP guide to scheduling](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_schedule)

---

The WinSCP can even [generate a script template](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl) from an [imported FileZilla session](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_import).

For details, see the [guide to FileZilla automation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_filezilla_automation).

---

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*