# How to use FTP in powershell commandline to upload a file to OneDrive

Tags: powershell, ftp, onedrive

I am trying to upload a file to OneDrive with a command on the command line.
Everything I have found online for documentation and resources so far say I have to create an app with MS and OneDrive, get a token, and use the MS graph API... or to use a client such as Filezilla and leverage it's command line features.

Using filezilla in my instance is not an option, as I am attempting to keep a minimal install scenario.

I find it hard to believe one is unable to use the ol' trusty ftp   approach.
Has anyone tried this?

Comment: It looks like [OneDrive uses OAuth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/msa-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online) for authentication, which is probably more than you can implement in an afternoon. This [OneDrive Module on GitHub](https://github.com/MarcelMeurer/PowerShellGallery-OneDrive) looks fairly straightforward to implement, but it's still not FTP-simple. FTP as a protocol uses no encryption and consequently lacks the level of security demanded in the age of malicious hacking.

Comment: OneDrive does not support FTP. + And as [FileZilla does not have any command-line features](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24945709/850848), it looks like the resource you have read is not very credible.

Comment: This may help.  It is for oneDrive for Business.   http://spsb.ca/o365/2017/06/15/UploadFiletooneDrive.html