# Schedule an automatic FTP upload on Windows with WinSCP

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, winscp

Let me preface this with a disclaimer, I have never executed scripts on the UI of WinSCP.

I have a program on our server that generates a text file that I want to be sent to our organization's shared drive. While looking through the internet I came across a few solutions, such as the code below. (Credentials have been left out for obvious reasons)

```
option batch abort
option confirm off
open ftp://user:pass@server
synchronize local U:\DO Unitization\Team Member Folders\xxxxxxxx
exit
```

This is then saved as a `.txt` (`abc.txt`)

Then executed manually as `winscp.com /script=abc.txt`

This is not what I want, seeing as thought the whole purpose was to automate this. Also, only one file actually needs to be sent, not everything in the directory. As I said above, my knowledge is lacking in this area so I apologize for any miscommunication.

Thank you,
Joshua Averbuch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a start, see [WinSCP guide to automating file transfers to FTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation).

A simple batch file (`upload.bat`) to upload a file to FTP server with WinSCP looks like:

```
winscp.com /log=c:\path\ftp.log /command ^
    "open ftp://user:password@example.com/" ^
    "put ""U:\DO Unitization\Team Member Folders\xxxxxxxx\file.txt"" ""/remote/path/""" ^
    "exit"
```

You can have the [batch file generated by WinSCP GUI](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating) for you.

---

For scheduling, simply use the Windows Scheduler.
For details see another [WinSCP guide to scheduling file transfers to FTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_schedule).

---

Similarly for a download: [How to schedule an automatic FTP download on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21293019/850848)

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I needed